# jar does not run on JWS

Tags: java, process, java-web-start, runtime.exec

I have a jar which I am running using JWS which run perfectly fine. In that application I have a button on click of which it executes another executable jar. This executable jar is present in the main jar.

On click of that button in Swing application I have the code:

```
java -jar executable.jar
```

I run this code using RunTime. But this doesn't work.

Comment: OK.. and what is your question? *"This executable jar is present in the main jar."*  The Java command cannot work with a Jar that is inside another Jar, it needs to be extracted to the local file system first.  Another tip:  See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Comment: Also.. be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.

Comment: How do we make sure that the jar gets copies to the local file system may to the home directory.

Comment: *"How do we make sure that the jar gets copies to the local file system.."*  If it start out in one of your Jars, you copy it (using Java code).  *"..may to the home directory."* I guess by 'home directory' you mean `user.home`?  But I don't understand the start of that ..'may to..' ..?

Comment: So I have packaged the executable jar in the main jar and started the main jar using JWS. but at the time of deployment it actually exploded that executable jar and now my program tries to find executable.jar which obviously it wont find because now it is exploded and it doesn't exist in the package format. (executable.jar)

Comment: Use `getResource(..)` to fin either the Jar or the classes in it.  The Jar in question (even if it is expanded) will be on the run-time class-path and will be accessible to the context class loader.  *"So I have packaged the executable jar in the main jar.."*  Bu what, *exactly* DYM mean by that?  If an IDE created a 'fat Jar` it would unpackage the Jar to be run and include the loose resources (e.g. `.class` files) in the main Jar.  Instead it should be that the `.jar` itself is located inside the other Jar file of the JWS app.